# Annual Data to quarterly data in R

Tags: r

So I have a data set that I would like to convert to quarters. So far I am able to convert from quarters to annual using the code below: 
data = Quandl("FRED/GDP", collapse="annual")

But I would like to do the reverse. Anything thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the collapse argument:

```
data = Quandl("FRED/GDP")
# head(data)
# Date    Value
# 1 2017-10-01 19736.49
# 2 2017-07-01 19500.60
# 3 2017-04-01 19250.01
# 4 2017-01-01 19057.71
# 5 2016-10-01 18905.54
# 6 2016-07-01 18729.13
```

Comment: I understand. But is there a code to actually convert annual data to quarterly.

Comment: Logically it is not possible to take an annual series and disaggregate it to it's original values.

Comment: Okay can you provide me with the general code to convert quarterly data to yearly.

Comment: If you open a new question, and provide a reproducible example of the data you want to aggregate I would be happy to help.